# Web Service Response SetValues giving Ljava.lang.Object;@ in Spreadsheet

Tags: web-services, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am calling a web service. 
I get a response, which when logged in the Logger is perfectly legible.
When inserted into a spreadsheet, I get Ljava.lang.Object;@ in the cell.
What do I need to do to get the data in the object to display properly?

```
function getRoomAvailability(){
 ...

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, headers);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(response);
  Logger.log(data);
  ss.getSheetByName("Room").getRange(1,1,1,1).setValues([data]);
}
```

I see the following in the log:

`[19-04-14 22:33:31:507 BST] [{"room_id":1,"room_availability":[{"date":"2019-04-20","available":"Yes"},{"date":"2019-04-21","available":"Yes"},{"date":"2019-04-22","available":"No"},{"date":"2019-04-23","available":"Yes"},{"date":"2019-04-24","available":"Yes"},{"date":"2019-04-25","available":"Yes"}]}]`

`[19-04-14 22:33:31:507 BST] [{room_id=1, room_availability=[{date=2019-04-20, available=Yes}, {date=2019-04-21, available=Yes}, {date=2019-04-22, available=No}, {date=2019-04-23, available=Yes}, {date=2019-04-24, available=Yes}, {date=2019-04-25, available=Yes}]}]`

In the spreadsheet, I see

`{room_id=1, room_availability=[Ljava.lang.Object;@676b6111}`

Comment: setValues accepts a 2D array. When another array inside a 2D array is encountered, it converts into this java object. Why not just `setValue(response)`?

Comment: Thanks TheMaster.  I have c.1000 responses (in a `for` loop), so was pushing them into an array to avoid multiple `setValue()` calls.  Is there a simple way to pull the arrays apart?

Comment: That's a different question. It'd  be better to Ask a new question.